# Android split ActionBar not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new with android ... i want to have a simple activity with a bottom action Bar in all tutorials it's mentionned that there is a way with

```
android:uiOptions=”splitActionBarWhenNarrow”
```

but it does not work on tablet or smal device even when i added

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity>
```

this is my manifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".launchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
           >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android 5.0's default theme (`Theme.Material`) does not support the split action bar. Neither does the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport anymore, though it used to.

Your options are either to switch to theme based off of `Theme.Holo`, put your own bar at the bottom of the screen (e.g., a `Toolbar`), or simply redesign your UI to avoid the split action bar.

Comment: i changed apptheme like this but the app does not run anymore
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: @elpazio: If by "does not run anymore", you mean that your app crashes, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @elpazio: OK, you are attempting to use `appcompat-v7` as an action bar backport. I do not see that in your Gradle build file, but perhaps it's just not what is in the code listing in your question. Regardless, `appcompat-v7` requires `Theme.AppCompat` and does not support a split action bar at all.

Comment: do you have any good tutorial to make a menu with a toolbar ?

Comment: @elpazio: Not handy, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fully agree with @CommonsWare [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791797/2956344).
I just add a note.

> If you build your app only for Lolipop(5.0) or higher(for now) the action bar may be represented by any [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) widget within the application layout. You can align components(also split them) inside since you are want.